# Cannot Deactivate Facebook Account due Invisible Apps

Tags: facebook, account

i just wanna to deactivate my facebook account but it said i should deleting all apps which i was the only one developer [(Valista (300960046610265))], i search the ID but there is nothing and automatically redirected to http://developers.facebook.com/ ? is this bug? is there anyway to deleting this invisible apps? i remember creating this apps to make Timeline display, just before Facebook announce First timeline as his official display.

i really" need to deactivate this account pls...

Comment: it has been for 2 week, the help pages just giving me FAQ with prepared question not with exact match....

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between deleting and deactivating facebook accounts. You may be able to bypass this problem by deleting the account, rather than deactivating it. Note below.

> **How do I permanently delete my account?**
>
> If you deactivate your account, your timeline disappears from the Facebook service immediately. People on Facebook won't be able to search for you, though some info, like messages you sent, may still be visible to others. We also save your timeline information (ex: friends, photos, interests, etc.) in case you want to come back.
>
> If you don't think you'll use Facebook again, you can request to have your account permanently deleted. Please keep in mind that you won't be able to reactivate your account or retrieve anything you've added. Before you do this, you may want to download a copy of your info from Facebook. Then, **if you'd like your account permanently deleted with no option for recovery**, log into your account and fill out this form.

this is taken from this page link:

https://www.facebook.com/help/224562897555674/#How-do-I-permanently-delete-my-account?

If this doesn't work, you can go to the Facebook Developers support:

https://developers.facebook.com/support/

This Stack forum Web Applications, may be more suitable for this type of question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq   I tried searching it and could not find a similar question.

Let me know if this doesn't solve your problem.